# Retrieve a file from an authenticated server on intranet and server it to the client

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am currently building my project locally using MVC.

The user enters some search information and is presented with a link to download a file in Vox format that exists somewhere else on the network.

That other server has a shared drive with authentication.

I need to have my controller grab that file and spit it out to the client for download.

What is the best approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the best approach?

By exposing a controller action that returns a `FileResult`:

```
public ActionResult Download()
{
    byte[] file = ... go and fetch the file contents from wherever it is stored
    return File(file, "some MIME type", "filename.someextension");
}
```

and then inside your view provide a link to the user so that he can download:

```
@Html.ActionLink("download the Vox file", "Download")
```

Comment: How do i fetch it if that server needs a login and pass?

Comment: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.

Comment: What protocol does this server talk? How should the username be provided?